# Figure Out Which Merged Table Cells Would Have Been Clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to figure out which cell position is clicked if you have merged table cells? We have 20 cells etc merged together and we would like to figure out if the user has clicked on what would have been for example the 7th cell

We have merged cells which mean specific things but we now need to figure out logically which cell was clicked by a user (even though they are merged).

Is this possible?

Comment: database / php maybe?

Comment: I don't get how server side is going to help me here? I have a single long TD that is made up of multiple cells merged together. I need to figure out which cell offset etc the client has clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can judge it based on the dimensions of unmerged cells in the same table. Here is an example using jQuery (just because it's much more concise than native JS to demonstrate this point):

```
var $mergedTd = $('td.myMergedTd'),
    $unmergedThs = $('th');

$mergedTd.click(function(e) {
  var clickedUnmergedIndex = 0;
  $unmergedThs.each(function(i) {
    var $th = $(this);
    if(e.pageX < $th.pageX + $th.width()) {
      clickedUnmergedIndex = i;
    } else {
      // Stop iterating; we've found the unmerged index
      return false;
    }
  });

  alert('You just clicked 0-based cell index #' + clickedUnmergedIndex);
});
```

Comment: jQuery is no issue we use that anyway. Looks promising. I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep two copies of that table in DOM. One visible and one hidden. You take click events on the visible table, and before you merge the cells, mark the clicked cell (e.g. add a data attribute to it indicating it was marked such as data-marked='1') and copy that table to the hidden one.